Draw 2D Shapes to bitmap using python GPU module
I want to create some dynamic helper bitmaps for my addon. I'me struggling a lot with just getting stuff drawn to bitmap using gpu module. I can get it working with numpy and directly manipulating the pixel arrays but that's not efficient at all, so i'd much rather get it working using gpu.
The following code only ever saves a pitch black image, I could really use some help to figure out my mistake, there's very little info about this...
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import numpy as np
import os

class SimpleDrawTestOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_draw_test"
    bl_label = "Simple Draw Test"

    def execute(self, context):
        width, height = 512, 512  # Image dimensions
        background_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)  # Red background for visibility

        # Create an offscreen buffer for rendering
        offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(width, height)

        # Bind the offscreen buffer for rendering
        with offscreen.bind():
            # Set the viewport to match the offscreen buffer size
            gpu.state.viewport_set(0, 0, width, height)

            # Clear the screen by drawing a full-screen quad with the background color
            self.clear_color_quad(background_color)

            # Save the rendered image to a file
            self.save_image(context, offscreen)

        offscreen.free()

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def clear_color_quad(self, color):
        # Shader and quad setup
        shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')
        shader.bind()
        shader.uniform_float("color", color)
        
        # Define the vertices of a full-screen quad
        vertices = np.array([
            (-1.0, -1.0),  # Bottom left
            (1.0, -1.0),   # Bottom right
            (1.0, 1.0),    # Top right
            (-1.0, 1.0)    # Top left
        ], dtype=np.float32)
        
        # Batch to draw the quad
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRI_FAN', {"pos": vertices})
        batch.draw(shader)

    def save_image(self, context, offscreen):
        # Read the pixels from the offscreen buffer
        buffer = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get().read_color(0, 0, offscreen.width, offscreen.height, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')

        # Convert the buffer to a flattened list
        buffer = np.array(buffer).flatten()

        # Create an image and assign pixel values
        image = bpy.data.images.new("Rendered Image", width=offscreen.width, height=offscreen.height)
        image.pixels = buffer.tolist()

        # Get the file path to save the image
        if bpy.data.filepath:
            output_dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
        else:
            output_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")

        image_path = os.path.join(output_dir, "simple_test_output.png")

        # Save the image
        image.filepath_raw = image_path
        image.file_format = 'PNG'
        image.save()

        self.report({'INFO'}, f"Image saved to {image_path}")

# Register the operator
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleDrawTestOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleDrawTestOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.object.simple_draw_test()

It doesn't need to save to disk, but before i get to showing a dynamic bitmap in UI, I at least want to get the drawing to work somehow...
